# React Redux with Typescript, Property Not Available in Reducer from ActionType

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am learning React with typescript and is currently facing problem while implementing Reducer in Redux.

These are my action types

```
import { LoginResponseInterface } from "../../interfaces/APIResponseInterface";

export const UserActionConst = {
  LOGIN_REQUEST: "USER_LOGIN_REQUEST",
  LOGIN_SUCCESS: "USER_LOGIN_REQUEST",
  LOGIN_FALIURE: "USER_LOGIN_REQUEST",

  LOGOUT: "USER_LOGOUT",
};

export interface LoginRequestAction {
  type: typeof UserActionConst.LOGIN_REQUEST;
}

export interface LoginSuccessAction {
  type: typeof UserActionConst.LOGIN_SUCCESS;
  payload: LoginResponseInterface;
}

export interface LoginFaliureAction {
  type: typeof UserActionConst.LOGIN_FALIURE;
}

export type UserActionsTypes =
  | LoginRequestAction
  | LoginSuccessAction
  | LoginFaliureAction;
```

And below is my reducer code

```
const initialState: IUserState = {
  isLoading: false,
  isLoggedIn: false,
  loggedInResponse: undefined,
};
export const userReducer = (
  state: IUserState = initialState,
  action: UserActionsTypes
): IUserState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UserActionConst.LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, isLoading: true };
    case UserActionConst.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isLoggedIn: true,
        loggedInResponse: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

In this reducer my action type is UserActionType but when I try to access the property payload it's not available in IntelliSense and compiler complains about it. I am attaching a screenshot of the same.

If I try to use that type on a constant then the payload is available. Can you kindly help me identifying the issue with my reducer?

[image: Property Not Available]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your actions constants have the same string so typescript can't separate the interfaces.

You need to define different action type names and add `as const` to the object containing the constants

```
export const UserActionConst = {
  LOGIN_REQUEST: "USER_LOGIN_REQUEST",
  LOGIN_SUCCESS: "USER_LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS",
  LOGIN_FALIURE: "USER_LOGIN_REQUEST_FAILURE",
} as const
```

Another option is the make it an `enum`

```
export enum UserActionConst {
  LOGIN_REQUEST = "USER_LOGIN_REQUEST",
  LOGIN_SUCCESS = "USER_LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS",
  LOGIN_FALIURE = "USER_LOGIN_REQUEST_FAILURE",
}
```

Comment: The enum option works and thanks for making the things clear as well. God Bless You and Stay Safe.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I've used redux but you are missing the action creators.

```
export const LoginRequest = () => ({
  type: UserActionConst.LOGIN_REQUEST,
})

export const LoginSuccess = (payload: LoginResponseInterface) => ({
  type: UserActionConst.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  payload,
})

export const LoginFaliure = () => ({
  type: UserActionConst.LOGIN_FALIURE,
})
```

I also recommend you use React's useContext instead of redux. Does the same thing but its built into React.